# Java Regex Arguments

Tags: java, regex, arguments

So if I wished to replace all numbers with a given value, I could just use

```
"hello8".replaceAll("[1-9]", "!");
```

> hello!

Now is there a way to get the number that is actually being matched and add that to the string?

e.g.

> hello!8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to set a capturing group:

```
"hello8".replaceAll("([1-9])", "!$1");
```

Another option is to use `$0`, which means the whole match:

```
"hello8".replaceAll("[1-9]", "!$0");
```

See also: [regular-expressions.info/java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
"hello8".replaceAll("([1-9])", "!$1");
```

See [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
String s = "hello8";
String y = null;
String t = null;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[1-9]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    y = (m.group());
    t = "!"+y;
    s = s.replace(y.toString(), t.toString());
}
System.out.println(s);
```