# JSON - rewrite string to numbers without quotes

Tags: json, regex, intellij-idea, rename

Hellou,

How can rename this:

```
"Id": "3",
```

to this:

```
"Id": 3,
```

I have a long file with string records.

I try use IntelliJ renamer with this formula `"\d+"` but `$0` return completly string with quotes.

Comment: Well, try `"(\d+)"` and replace with `$1` (if that is really the case when you want to replace all digits inside `"` with the digits themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look at how [regex groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4475200/1140085) work.

The `$0` will always represent the entire match. To get a subsection of it (the number in your case) you need to use parenthesis around the relevant portions to create a capturing group and then you can reference each group by a 1-based index.

So in your case, a pattern of `"(\d+?)"` on your sample string would return `"3"` for `$0` (the entire match), and `3` for `$1` (the first capturing group).

Comment: Thanx very much! I also try to use groups, but with only $0